# Is there a way to play mp3 files in one mediaplayer object?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can play a sound using Mediaplayer class in java android.
I make a Mediaplayer object like this.

```
Mediaplayer mp=Mediaplayer.create(this,R.raw.mysong);
```

And then start it but what if i have more than one song and have to play it. Do I need to make objects for everyone of them. What i am trying to say is does Mediaplayer class have any kind of method or thing that i can clear the old song and put new song for playing?

Hope you get what i say

I could really appreciate it with a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your mediaplayer object without ".create" like this
    Mediaplayer mp=new Mediaplayer();
Then you just set the source of it *note the source must be in uri format*
    mp.setDataSource(this,uri);
But before starting it you have to prepare first like this:
    mp.prepare();
Then start.
And when you wanted to change the source again first stop the mp then set another source 
Hope you get it.

Answer (score 4):

Create only one object as you've done ,but like this

```
Mediaplayer mp = new MediaPLayer();
```

Change the data source:
If your source it’s a uri just pass it to setDataSource , but if is a resource in raw folder use this to create an uri from the resource

```
    int resourceId = R.raw.other_song

    uri uriSound = Uri.Builder()
        .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
        .authority(resources.getResourcePackageName(resourceId))
        .appendPath(resources.getResourceTypeName(resourceId))
        .appendPath(resources.getResourceEntryName(resourceId))
        .build()

mp.setDataSource(this , uriSound)
```

Prepare and start the media player when you want

```
mp.prepare()
mp.start()
```